# Windows will not boot after a restart of my Mac Pro, only after a cold shutdown and startup

Tags: bootcamp, windows, startup, mac-pro, reboot

I am currently experiencing a very strange issue regarding booting into Windows 7 64-bit (installed on its own 1TB HDD). If I *restart* my Mac Pro, hold down the option key, and select my Windows partition, I get a black screen and the fans spin up. However, if I completely power down the machine and cold boot it, I am able to hold down the option key and select Windows and boot successfully. So, essentially, I am able to boot into Windows only after a cold boot, and not a restart due to the aforementioned problems.

This same issue occurs even when trying to boot to the Windows 7 installation DVD, so I know it  doesn't have anything to do with my Windows installation.  Rebooting from Windows to OS X works perfectly.  I have tried running the Apple Hardware Test and it detected no issues.  I also ran TechTool Deluxe.  Any help is greatly appreciated!